# converting videos with php and ffmpeg

Tags: php

how can i upload and convert the video to mp4 behind the scene so that if user uploads a video than the user could work/visit on rest of site and once the video is converted it displays in the users control panel....!!
i want to do this without ffmpeg........
if there is no way out than i will want to use ffmpeg.....!!

Comment: are you asking how to convert a video, or how to convert it in the background?

Comment: i am just asking how to convert it in the background while i have linux or window hosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198052/run-a-ffmpeg-process-in-the-background), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540565/how-to-fork-a-video-conversion-process-into-background-in-php)