# Programmatically get path to php

Tags: php, apache, path, exec

I'd like to do a similar thing than [How to "fork" a video conversion process into background, in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540565/how-to-fork-a-video-conversion-process-into-background-in-php) :

```
exec("/usr/bin/php ./foo.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");  // executed in Apache
```

However, this will run on a variety of platforms : my machine, where php is compiled in ~/, windows, several prod servers...

Is there a way to programmatically get the "/usr/bin/php" part ?

Things I could think of :

- get the current pid, guess executable from it
- in C, the first argument is the path to the executable, maybe there is something similar

Comment: If you expect to use this code in a webpage request (you tagged it apache), you'll never know. Apache isn't calling any PHP binary in the common configurations.

Comment: @Dan What are "common configurations?" suPHP? That's called using binaries (php-cgi).

Comment: PHP as a module, not as a CGI, is the default and most common configuration. PHP code runs under the apache process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to simply make sure the `php` CLI binary is found in `$PATH` environment variable, and then just use `php /path/to/foo.php`.

On UNIX you can also use `/usr/bin/env php` which will execute the first `php` binary found in `$PATH`. But that obviously won't work in Windows.

Lastly one obvious way is to have the location to `PHP` as a configurable option, and use the user-specified path when appropriate.

Comment: ok, that's what I feared. Since php can refer to either php4 or php5 (I need php5) I went the config way. Thanks.